# Angular app in new browser tabs not working

Tags: angular, symfony

I have two application the first one is developped on symfony 4 and it works perfectly, the other one is developped using angular.
i created a virtualhost file for the website where the angular app and symfony 4 works pefectly, the probléme is when i open the angular app  in new tab it gives me a symfony error route not found instead of using the angular app :

```
No route found for "GET /reviewer/reviewerApp/info/21
```

the angular app works perfectely as single page app but when i use it as a link in other pages like href="domain.com/reviewer/reviewerApp/info/21" it doesn't work.

i added this rewrite rule inside a virtualhost for the angular 8 app but it doesn't work :

```
RewriteRule ^/reviewer/(.+)$ /opt/application/php/reviewerApp/index.html?path=$1 [L]
```

where /opt/application/php/reviewerApp/ is the folder of my angular 8 app.
can someone help me.
thanks in advance